# .nuget include file from other project

Tags: nuget, teamcity, include-path, nuget-spec, octopack

I have three visual studio database projects with .sql files. Instead of publishing the projects to a database, the SQL needs to be executed at a specific moment.

I added another project to package everything into one nuget package (including some generic scripts). So the .nuspec file should specify the SQL files that need to be included.

```
<file src="..\otherproject\code.sql" target="Content" />
```

We use TeamCity to build our projects and Octopus Deploy to pack the nuget packages. When TeamCity tries to build the package OctoPack says it can't find the file:

> error OCTONUGET: File not found:
>   '..\otherproject\code.sql'.

I've checked, the file is present on the build server on the requested location.

How to access the parent folder? Or is there another way to include files from other projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is perfectly fine. My .nuspec file was named like the solution instead of the project.